# Removing the top border from a Cayley table?

Tags: tables

Is there a specific way, using `tabular`, to remove the top border of my table?

I can not tell if the tables on Stackexchange are result of the browser layout or something that I am missing.

Thank you for your time and help!

Here is a sample of my code

```latex
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \noindent 
    \begin{tabular}{c ||  c | c | c}
        \cline{1-4}
        * & x & y & z\\
        \hline
        x & x & y & z\\
        \hline
        y & y & x & x\\
        \hline
        z & y & x & x\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image: Example Table]

I don't want the line above * | x | y | z

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: All you have to do to achieve your formatting objective is to delete the instruction `\cline{1-4}`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue has already been solved in a comment.

Comment: How is this question related to "tables on Stackexchange"? I don't quite get it ..

Comment: @Mico Thank you!!